# JetBrain Idea android xml element is not allowed here

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, intellij-idea

JetBrain Idea android xml element is not allowed here.

[I found this tutorial but I still don't understand how to resolve this problem](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/code-inspections/)

I got something like this http://clip2net.com/s/2I0HI?dw=1

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="10"
    android:rowCount="10">

    <TextView
        style="@style/GlobalTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/lbl_player_kicking_kicking"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_top"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/GlobalTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom"
        android:text="@string/lbl_player_receiving_rec"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:padding="10dp" />
    </GridLayout >
```

Comment: Could you show us the complete xml layout?

Comment: Please zip and share a sample project that will reproduce the problem in IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using SDK level 14 or up with your project.

Open project properties, *File* > *Project Structure* and select *Project*. Under *Project SDK* it must say *Android 4.0 platform* (or newer).

Comment: problem not in GridLayout it's happens in any element

Comment: @KostyRudenko Does it compiles ?

Comment: Yes.But edit xml file I can only in design maker not in text.When i try to use Ctlr+Space i got "No suggestions"

Comment: @KostyRudenko Then IDEA hasn't integrated well with SDK. You should re-setup the IDE with android SDK, create a new project and import source files to it.